# Broken Windows startup after repartitioning drive

Tags: bootcamp

I run Windows 10 on my boot camp partition. Yesterday I created a new partition on my disk to store my shared documents between two operating systems by resizing the OS X partition.

Today I noticed that Windows doesn't load.

[image]

I have the installation media but didn't want to mess with partitions as I know nothing about how boot camp works.

Is there a way I can repair my Windows installation or do I have to reinstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should never try to change drive partitions under Windows (Boot Camp): this makes Windows unbootable. I do afraid that now you have to re-create boot camp partition and reinstall Windows.

Anyway there're (proved by people) ways (see links [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76988/how-to-create-third-partition-after-macintosh-hd-and-boot-camp-partitions), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147556/how-to-create-third-partition-on-a-mac-with-mavericks-and-bootcamp), [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22528/macbook-air-lion-windows-7-boot-camp-shared-partition)) to achieve what you want.

PS. I personally prefer and recommend external Thunderbolt drive for the 3rd partition shared between mac/windows

Comment: I ended up formatting the drive and reinstalling everything.